# Using two policies together in a single S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I am new to Amazon S3 and just created my first bucket. I need two important policies to be implemented on the bucket which are as follows:

1. First, policy for allowing only downloads from my own website (via HTTP referrer)
2. Secondly, I want to make all objects in the bucket public.

I have got two different codes of policies for my needs, but now I can't put them together to achieve the said goals. Please help me joining these too policies together so I achieve what I want.

For allowing referrer downloads:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy example",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originated from www.example.com and example.com",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "URL/*",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

For making objects public:

```
{
    "Sid": "...",
    "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": [ "*" ]
    }
}
```

Comment: The first policy should be all you need.  If the referrer matches the pattern, access is allowed.  Of course, you need to keep in mind that that's very weak protection but you should not need to make things "public" if you already have the "Allow" policy that you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found another solution as this one was not supported by most mobile browsers (who don't send HTTP Referrer Header). I have disabled the public access and everything works fine. I hope it will not create any issues :)